# Getting EntityFramework error when running the same application on Windows 8

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, windows-8

My application works great on Windows 7 - It can connect to a SQL database using EF and everything connects and works. When running the same application (same version) on a Windows 8 PC, I get the following error:

```
Database failed to Open. Message: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

What can I do to make the application work correctly on Windows 8 too?

I looked at my application configuration and nothing changed recently. I'm also not using the `DbProviderFactories` tag that I've read can cause such error.

Comment: Does the system have an ADO.NET provider for SQL Server installed?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: There's some code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12kxkt25%28v=vs.80%29.aspx that shows how to enumerate the registered providers. Having said that, it looks as though .NET installs a provider for SQL so it should probably be there.

Comment: Check your machine.config for corruption